# Export more than 50 Freeform submissions (without a lot of scrolling)

Tags: plugin-freeform

We've got a site with several Freeform forms, and my client has noticed that when they use Freeform's "Export CSV" they only get the first 50. That's because you need to select all the submissions, then export them – and if you've not scrolled down several times to force all of the other entries to load in, you'll only get the 50 that were initially shown.

Does anyone know a way round this? If you've got hundreds of submissions it feels a bit clunky to have to trigger the AJAXing in of entries before you can export them.

We're on Craft 2.6.3011, Freeform 1.8.6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Sprout Reports](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/reports) is a flexible reporting plugin that allows you to create custom queries and export the results as CSV.

You could write a custom report using the default Twig Template or Custom Query reports building a report using Freeform variables in your Twig templates or a MySQL query that queries the report Freeform content table directly.

If you'd like to give your users settings, such as which Form to export submissions from, you can add settings to a custom Twig Template report or write a custom integration to define settings and handle your query using PHP.

Comment: Thanks Ben, will take a look. If anyone knows a way to get Freeform to do this directly that would still be great (it's more intuitive for my client to go where the forms are) but this sounds like a good fallback if that's not possible...

Comment: Hi again Ben. Just to check: do you think I'd be able to have the user select any Freeform form and Sprout Reports would create a CSV of whatever fields that form has? Or would there be any limitation to what data could be included? My client creates a lot of their own Freeform forms, so I guess this would only work if I could set it up once and it'd work for all possible forms they create...

Comment: Sprout Reports lets you create any query you want. So, the main limitation is just the complexity of the type of query you need to create and your comfort level building that query.  It will be easier to return simple field types that store their content in the content table columns. It may require a more advanced PHP-driven custom report to return fields with more advanced data types like relations fields. If you can build the query you want in Twig, MySQL, or PHP, Sprout Reports can let you export it.

Comment: Ok thanks Ben. I'm most comfortable in Twig, so will see how feasible it is to export everything that way.